# Уменьшить количество div'ов

Tags: html, css, css3, css-grid

Подскажите, можно ли в данном примере обойтись без `<div class="more">...</div>`?

```css
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.more {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    grid-column-gap: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="photo">
    <img src="https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-KRym5tq8hu8/VwzHCS14M_I/AAAAAAAABQI/rSpEJlsPOqM9AUhuPYRo5hA2bKzB3ZCNwCLcB/s1600/tekstura-dolki-apelsin.jpg">
    <div class="more">
        <img src="https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-KRym5tq8hu8/VwzHCS14M_I/AAAAAAAABQI/rSpEJlsPOqM9AUhuPYRo5hA2bKzB3ZCNwCLcB/s1600/tekstura-dolki-apelsin.jpg">
        <img src="https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-KRym5tq8hu8/VwzHCS14M_I/AAAAAAAABQI/rSpEJlsPOqM9AUhuPYRo5hA2bKzB3ZCNwCLcB/s1600/tekstura-dolki-apelsin.jpg">
        <img src="https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-KRym5tq8hu8/VwzHCS14M_I/AAAAAAAABQI/rSpEJlsPOqM9AUhuPYRo5hA2bKzB3ZCNwCLcB/s1600/tekstura-dolki-apelsin.jpg">
        <img src="https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-KRym5tq8hu8/VwzHCS14M_I/AAAAAAAABQI/rSpEJlsPOqM9AUhuPYRo5hA2bKzB3ZCNwCLcB/s1600/tekstura-dolki-apelsin.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Примените псевдо-класс `:first-child`, чтобы задать стили для первой картинки. Свойство `grid-row` говорит, что нужно занять первую строчку (между первой и второй линией), `grid-column` растягивает элемент по всей ширине контейнера (от первой до последней линии).

```css
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.photos {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    grid-gap: 10px;
}

.photos :first-child {
    grid-row: 1 / 2;  /* занимает первую строчку */
    grid-column: 1 / -1;  /* и все доступные колонки */
}
```

```html
<div class="photos">
    <img src="https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-KRym5tq8hu8/VwzHCS14M_I/AAAAAAAABQI/rSpEJlsPOqM9AUhuPYRo5hA2bKzB3ZCNwCLcB/s1600/tekstura-dolki-apelsin.jpg">
    <img src="https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-KRym5tq8hu8/VwzHCS14M_I/AAAAAAAABQI/rSpEJlsPOqM9AUhuPYRo5hA2bKzB3ZCNwCLcB/s1600/tekstura-dolki-apelsin.jpg">
    <img src="https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-KRym5tq8hu8/VwzHCS14M_I/AAAAAAAABQI/rSpEJlsPOqM9AUhuPYRo5hA2bKzB3ZCNwCLcB/s1600/tekstura-dolki-apelsin.jpg">
    <img src="https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-KRym5tq8hu8/VwzHCS14M_I/AAAAAAAABQI/rSpEJlsPOqM9AUhuPYRo5hA2bKzB3ZCNwCLcB/s1600/tekstura-dolki-apelsin.jpg">
    <img src="https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-KRym5tq8hu8/VwzHCS14M_I/AAAAAAAABQI/rSpEJlsPOqM9AUhuPYRo5hA2bKzB3ZCNwCLcB/s1600/tekstura-dolki-apelsin.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: Свойство `grid-row` в данном примере избыточно.

Answer (score 3):

Если результат должен быть такой же как в вашем сниппете, то да, но для этого нужно кое-что изменить.

```css
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

/* весь photo превращяется в grid */
.photo {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    grid-gap: 10px;
}

/* А первая картинка в блоке photo становится шириной от 1 ячейки сетки, до 4й */
.photo img:first-child {
    grid-column: 1 / span 4;
}
```

```html
<div class="photo">
    <img src="https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-KRym5tq8hu8/VwzHCS14M_I/AAAAAAAABQI/rSpEJlsPOqM9AUhuPYRo5hA2bKzB3ZCNwCLcB/s1600/tekstura-dolki-apelsin.jpg">
    <img src="https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-KRym5tq8hu8/VwzHCS14M_I/AAAAAAAABQI/rSpEJlsPOqM9AUhuPYRo5hA2bKzB3ZCNwCLcB/s1600/tekstura-dolki-apelsin.jpg">
    <img src="https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-KRym5tq8hu8/VwzHCS14M_I/AAAAAAAABQI/rSpEJlsPOqM9AUhuPYRo5hA2bKzB3ZCNwCLcB/s1600/tekstura-dolki-apelsin.jpg">
    <img src="https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-KRym5tq8hu8/VwzHCS14M_I/AAAAAAAABQI/rSpEJlsPOqM9AUhuPYRo5hA2bKzB3ZCNwCLcB/s1600/tekstura-dolki-apelsin.jpg">
    <img src="https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-KRym5tq8hu8/VwzHCS14M_I/AAAAAAAABQI/rSpEJlsPOqM9AUhuPYRo5hA2bKzB3ZCNwCLcB/s1600/tekstura-dolki-apelsin.jpg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант, с помощью флексбокс — больше поддерживается браузерами, нежели гриды:

```css
.photo {
  align-items: flex-start;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.photo img {
  margin-right: 10px;
  width: calc(25% - 10px);
}

.photo img:first-child {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  width: 100%;
}

.photo img:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="photo">
  <img src="https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-KRym5tq8hu8/VwzHCS14M_I/AAAAAAAABQI/rSpEJlsPOqM9AUhuPYRo5hA2bKzB3ZCNwCLcB/s1600/tekstura-dolki-apelsin.jpg">
  <img src="https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-KRym5tq8hu8/VwzHCS14M_I/AAAAAAAABQI/rSpEJlsPOqM9AUhuPYRo5hA2bKzB3ZCNwCLcB/s1600/tekstura-dolki-apelsin.jpg">
  <img src="https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-KRym5tq8hu8/VwzHCS14M_I/AAAAAAAABQI/rSpEJlsPOqM9AUhuPYRo5hA2bKzB3ZCNwCLcB/s1600/tekstura-dolki-apelsin.jpg">
  <img src="https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-KRym5tq8hu8/VwzHCS14M_I/AAAAAAAABQI/rSpEJlsPOqM9AUhuPYRo5hA2bKzB3ZCNwCLcB/s1600/tekstura-dolki-apelsin.jpg">
  <img src="https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-KRym5tq8hu8/VwzHCS14M_I/AAAAAAAABQI/rSpEJlsPOqM9AUhuPYRo5hA2bKzB3ZCNwCLcB/s1600/tekstura-dolki-apelsin.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: Идея решения через Flexbox хороша, но отступы между элементами и элементами и `body` не совсем корректные. Исправленную версию написал [в своём ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/944378/220571).

Answer (score 0):

Улучшенная версия [ответа Kvilios](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/942353/220571):

```css
.photo {
  align-items: flex-start;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.photo img {
  /* 7.5px = 10px * (n / n - 1), где n — кол-во фотографий в ряду, в данном случае 4 */
  width: calc(25% - 7.5px);
}

.photo img:first-child {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}

.photo img:not(:first-child) + img {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="photo">
  <img src="https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-KRym5tq8hu8/VwzHCS14M_I/AAAAAAAABQI/rSpEJlsPOqM9AUhuPYRo5hA2bKzB3ZCNwCLcB/s1600/tekstura-dolki-apelsin.jpg">
  <img src="https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-KRym5tq8hu8/VwzHCS14M_I/AAAAAAAABQI/rSpEJlsPOqM9AUhuPYRo5hA2bKzB3ZCNwCLcB/s1600/tekstura-dolki-apelsin.jpg">
  <img src="https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-KRym5tq8hu8/VwzHCS14M_I/AAAAAAAABQI/rSpEJlsPOqM9AUhuPYRo5hA2bKzB3ZCNwCLcB/s1600/tekstura-dolki-apelsin.jpg">
  <img src="https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-KRym5tq8hu8/VwzHCS14M_I/AAAAAAAABQI/rSpEJlsPOqM9AUhuPYRo5hA2bKzB3ZCNwCLcB/s1600/tekstura-dolki-apelsin.jpg">
  <img src="https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-KRym5tq8hu8/VwzHCS14M_I/AAAAAAAABQI/rSpEJlsPOqM9AUhuPYRo5hA2bKzB3ZCNwCLcB/s1600/tekstura-dolki-apelsin.jpg">
</div>
```